# Drag-and-drop without the drag

Tags: command-line, x11, freedesktop, drag-and-drop

I sometimes need to drag-and-drop files onto an application. ([Example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48586/how-do-i-install-userscripts-in-chrome-on-linux) — but my question here is not installing Chrome userscripts.) One solution is to [use Dragbox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137905/can-i-drag-a-file-into-a-window-without-a-file-manager), which opens a window from which I can drag a file specified on the command line.

It's nice but I'd like to reduce the necessary mouse interaction. With Dragbox, I have to: arrange for both Dragbox and the drop zone to be visible; move the mouse cursor to the location where Dragbox displays the file; press the left mouse button; move the mouse cursor to the drop zone; release the cursor.

I'd like an interface that works more like copy-paste: run a command like `dragbox --more-magic foo`, then click on the drop zone. Or run the command then focus the drop zone and press a key. Is there a program to do that? Can it even be done with Freedesktop drag-and-drop?

Comment: Can `xkbset` / Mouse Keys be of assistance? See http://en.linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_use_the_numeric_keyboard_keys_as_mouse_in_XOrg and http://askubuntu.com/questions/68807/how-can-i-configure-mousekeys.

Comment: @Lambert No, I don't think so. Moving the cursor around with arrow keys is even more tedious than with a dedicated peripheral.

Answer (score 6):

2019 now but stil...

This is my current screenshot tool. The xdotool commands are relevant regarding how to automate a file drag.

[image]

Here the script (started via hotkey in the example):

```bsh
2.bin$ cat drag_into
#!/usr/bin/env bash
doc="$0 <filename|'shot'>

With filename: Drags given file to where the mouse is using dragon.
               Click to drop it (anywere).
With 'shot'  : File will be a shot of a an area to be selected.
               => 'drag_into shot' on a hotkey combo makes sense. 
"

cmd_shot="shot"
file=

exit_help () { echo -e "$doc"; exit 1; }

select_shot_area () {
    # create screen shot
    notify-send "Select area - we'll shoot it and drag to where the mouse is."
    cd "$HOME/Pictures/shots/" || exit 1
    rm -f "latest.png"
    scrot -s '%Y-%m-%d_$wx$h_scrot.png' -e 'ln -s $f latest.png'
    file="`readlink latest.png`"
}

main () {
    file="$1"
    test -z "$file" -o "$file" == "-h" && exit_help
    eval "$(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)" # into $X and $Y
    test "$file" == "$cmd_shot" && { select_shot_area || return 1; }
    killall dragon 2>/dev/null # No accidential drops of wrong items ...
    dragon --and-exit "$file" &
    while true; do
        xid="$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class  dragon | head -n 2)"
        test -z "$xid" || break
        sleep 0.05
    done
    xdotool mousemove --sync -w "$xid" 1 1 mousedown 1 mousemove $X $Y
    notify-send "Click to drop $file..."
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated in 2020

Comment: https://github.com/mwh/dragon to save someone else searching for the `dragon` tool (it's not in ubuntu yet)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Selenium**](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/overview/) for this task. It is an open source tool to interact  with web browsers. Assuming you use Arch Linux and want to write in python, install `python-selenium` aur package (or via pip: `pip install selenium`), then run `pip install webdriver-manager` (for automatically download needed version of driver that matches your browser version).

Selenium even [does not require you to drag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9735909/7869636) the required file, just pass an absolute path to file you want. Of course if you wish, you still can instead just simulate a click to an upload button or even dropping something to it.

You can work with the [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70088095/7869636) (previously opened) browser instead of opening a new window. In this case however you may need to use [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71857267/7869636) for selecting the currently gui active tab to correspond programmatically choosen active tab.

Comment: Selenium would work when dragging a file to a supported web browser, right?

Comment: I am not sure about interactive element selection in random web page. If you figure that out, then it may be possible, see code [here](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/drag-and-drop-in-selenium). In my case I know exactly where I want to drop the file (the page has a single input element with type file, and I select it), so I [automated it](https://gitlab.com/AndrewShark/pycharm-scripts/-/blob/main/upload_to_yandex_lms.py). Maybe try to list all input elements and show a dialog if there are several? But probably overkill for your use.

Answer (score 1):

[image: example on how drop it is used]

Found this question while trying to figure out how to solve this, I eventually went the route of developing a solution to fit my needs. I wanted to post it here for anyone in the future that might be interested in the solution i came up with.

You can find the source for **[drop](https://github.com/sillybanaja/drop)** here. To run it:

```bash
$ git clone https://github.com/sillybanaja/drop.git
$ cd drop
$ make
```

---

For context I want a simple way to drag-and-drop files from the terminal into windows that force drag-and-drop without having to drag the file or interact with a GUI.

`drop` is written in C using **[Xlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib)**, which is a lightweight library widely available on Unix-like systems. `drop` takes a list of filenames as arguments and allows you to drop them onto any application that supports XDND (X drag-and-drop), without requiring you to drag the files. Yay one less click!

Here's the basic usage: `drop filename ...`, and here's a example:

```bash
$ drop ~/Downloads/*.jpg file.txt /usr/local/bin/*
```

Also `drop` allows you to use globbing patterns like "~/Downloads/*.jpg". Once you have pressed enter you can navigate to the destination window and click where you want to drop the files. Press Escape at any time to close the program.